# Driver installation problem in Win7

Tags: windows-7, device-driver

I have an MSI created using installshield.
When I install that MSI on Windows XP, device is deteced. .sys file is created in C:\Windows\system32\drivers directory and C:\Windows\system32\driverstore also has the related device folders.
But the same MSI fails to install drivers on Window7. In other words, neither device is detected nor .sys file is created in C:\Windows\system32\drivers directory and C:\Windows\system32\driverstore also doesn't have the related device folders.

I would like to know what's wrong with the MSI.
what are settings required for an MSI to install kernel driver on Windows7

Thanks in advance for any useful information.

Comment: Do you afford buying DriverGenius Software? No matter Why your MSI file is not installing well, that program will search and find the suitable drivers for your system. I used it on Win 7 and it worked.

Comment: I created an MSI with the driver that I have developed. So, I want to know what settings are required to install it.

Comment: Is the driver package signed? Do you use legacyMode?

Comment: There is probably some condition in your setup installer that prevents installing the driver based on the operating system that's detected.  What does the setup installer code look like.  What does the setup installer log file indicate the reason for not installing the feature\component\file, if at all?

Answer (score 1):

If the installation program is built for 32-bit platform. it cannot install 64-bit drivers under 32-bit process. It might be the cause of your issue.

To workaround the issue, you can create a custom action and depending on windows platform, custom action will call DPInst.exe for 32-bit or 64-bit to install drivers,

This article [Driver Installation for 32-bit and 64 bit Platforms](http://www.google.com.vn/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBcQFjAA&url=http://download.microsoft.com/download/7/E/7/7E7662CF-CBEA-470B-A97E-CE7CE0D98DC2/32-64bit_install.docx&ei=KUPdTcWMJ42wuAPwtZG0Dw&usg=AFQjCNEPJkK1loOJd0RxGHCQcDRGzo5R6Q&sig2=u4ZAevmlHO9L1J8FdWtioA) gives the sample code for how to use 32-bit installation program to install 64-bit driver package on 64-bit platform

Answer (score 1):

I think InstallShield (modern ones) come with integration for [DIFx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463103.aspx) (driver installation framework), which is part of the WDK and comes in the form of merge modules and also DLLs. Either way, you can use the standard tools to integrate the merge modules even if InstallShield does not include direct support.

"Signing", however, is *not* enough. You need to have the driver since Vista signed in a special way that includes the root certificates (passing `/ac` when doing `signtool sign`) as part of the signature (early in the boot process there is no cert store available). Also, during installation the [Setup API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc185682%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is actually going to verify that the CAT file belonging to the driver has been cross-signed by MS (via WHQL). You have a CAT file and a proper INF file and the CAT file has been cross-signed, right?

If you have signtool (Windows SDK or WDK) use

```
signtool verify /kp /v <filename>
```

to verify the signature (`/v` is for verbose, you could use `/q` if you are only interested in the return code).

If those verifications fail, that's one root cause already.

Perform this check on both the CAT and the SYS files.